# npm ERR! code ENOENT react ,npm install not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

when I try `npm install` in my project folder it shows an error like this

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path D:\manoj\projects\keeper-3/package.json

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\manoj\projects\keeper-3\package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-01T18_05_41_278Z-debug-0.log
```

[It was a long one I've linked the log here](https://github.com/manojmj333/react/blob/main/2022-03-01T18_05_41_278Z-debug-0.log)

**its working i just forgot to install package.json**

Comment: Please share the debug log which is found under `C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-03-01T18_05_41_278Z-debug-0.log`

Comment: Hi, paste a content of your package.json file here. You have it in your project folder, isn't it?

Comment: I hope you're running "install" from a command prompt, and I hope you've "cd"'ed into your project directory (e.g. "cd d:\manoj\projects\keeper-3").  Correct?  And I hope you've verified that "package.json" exists in that project directory, correct?  Q: How exactly did you create the project?